# Could the *-trom ending in PIE be a zero-grade from agent suffix *-ter-/-tor-?

Tags: morphology, proto-indo-european

Given the agent suffix *-ter-* (which exhibited e-grade when meaning a profession or purpose and o-grade when meaning the recent perpetrator), can *-trom* suffix also be a zero grade from this one plus inanimate nomenative ending *-om*? Especially taking into account internal derivation. Just some examples.

> *u̯es-tēr* (tailor) -> *u̯es-tr-om* (wear)
>
> *a̯ero̯-tēr* (plowman) -> *a̯ero̯-tr-om* (plow)

On the other hand, Fortson lists *-tro-* suffix along with *-tlo-* suffix as separate instrumental suffixes. I wonder whether then was a similar agent suffix *-tel-* (cf Russian *prii̯a-tel* "friend", Greek *aristo-tel*)?

Comment: Shouldn't you name the language you're asking about?

Comment: Should be: Greek Ἀριστοτέλης "Aristoteles". They spoke Ancient/Old Greek there, not Modern Russian.

Comment: @Alex B. okay, what does it change? -es is an ending. The question is whether there was an agent suffix -tel- to which attested suffix -tl-/-tlo- is a zero-grade.

Comment: There is no suffix -tel- in Ἀριστοτέλης; the name is a compound whose second member is related to the noun τέλος 'end, purpose, etc.'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Jean Haudry, Proto-Indo-European *-tr-om indeed is *-ter with zero-grade and neuter ending.

Also according to him, PIE *-tel is an old phonetic variant of PIE *-ter.

Next to PIE *-tr-om, there is also PIE *-tl-om, as in Latin "(ob)staculum" from PIE *stéH₂-tlom.

Comment: Hello Mara and welcome! You said "According to Jean Haudry"... While it's not mandatory, if you could link the paper/book where this is stated (especially if readable as in Google Books), it would increase the quality of your answer. :D Just a note. :)

Comment: It's from Jean Haudry, "L'indo-européen", from the series "Que sais-je". I think, it's this one: (http://books.google.de/books?id=qXWyAAAAIAAJ&dq=editions:2YumY-pzIbsC&hl=de&redir_esc=y)